# Spring Boot 2.3 + Hikari + ojdbc11 + Oracle 21 проблема с Sys_Context

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

Мы на прошлой недели перешли с **Oracle 12.0.1** на **Oracle 21.0.1**. При запуска никаких проблем не было, система работала вроде отлично. Однако после запуска заметили что идет пересечения pool connections, т.е. во время работы одного пользователя с системой видны данные другого пользователя. **Sys_Context** тянет информацию другого пользователя.

application.yml

```
spring:   jmx:
    enabled: false   
    profiles: PROF   
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@client_ip_address:1521/orcl
      username: USER
      password: PASSWORD
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 30000
      idleTimeout: 30000
      minimum-idle: 5
      pool-name: HIKARIPOOL
      leak-detection-threshold: 600000
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>uz.dl</groupId>   <artifactId>main</artifactId>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   <packaging>jar</packaging>   <name>main</name>   <description>SYSTEM_NAME</description>   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->   </parent>   <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>   </properties>   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>   </dependencyManagement>   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
      <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core
-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
      <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
      <version>21.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>pl.jsolve</groupId>
      <artifactId>templ4docx</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>29.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>   </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                  <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/docker/backend</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>   </build> </project>
```

Подключение к Oracle 21c происходит через hikari

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SIcsLc {
  
  private final HikariDataSource hds;
  private final JwtTokenUtil jwt;
```

Думаю это связано с библиотеками. Потому что раньше у нас для подключения была библиотека ojdbc8 потом для работы с Oracle 21c перешли на ojdbc 11 и поменяли jdk 20.0.1. где может быть проблемы подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Где вызов `Sys_Context`?

Comment: Sys_Context вызывается в базе данных Oracle(пакеты, вющки и т.д)

Comment: ну покажите его